# VBA If statements spanning multiple line

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have this code:

```
For Each ARange In ws.Range("L1:L28000").Rows
    If ARange(1).Value = "John" Or ARange(1).Value = "Thomson" Or ARange(1).Value = "Mattson" Or ARange(1).Value = "Powers" Or ARange(1).Value = "Hermkens" Or ARange(1).Value = "Licka" Or ARange(1).Value = "Fout" Or ARange(1).Value = "Marrin" Or ARange(1).Value = "Fleming" Or ARange(1).Value = "Waiblinger" Or ARange(1).Value = "Lambertson" Or ARange(1).Value = "Solis" Or ARange(1).Value = "Deot" Or ARange(1).Value = "Large" Or ARange(1).Value = "Gannon" Or ARange(1).Value = "FAUGHNAN" Or ARange(1).Value = "COMPLIANCE" Or ARange(1).Value = "Jacobs" Or ARange(1).Value = "Powers" Or ARange(1).Value = "TSH" Or ARange(1).Value = "WRONG LOCATION CODE" Then
        If DRange Is Nothing Then
            Set DRange = ARange
        Else
            Set DRange = Union(DRange, ARange)
        End If
    End If
Next ARange
```

However, the first if statement is all one line I can I can not read without scrolling, can the code be broken up yet still function as intend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
If _
    ARange(1).Value = "John" Or ARange(1).Value = "Thomson" Or _
    ARange(1).Value = "Mattson" Or ARange(1).Value = "Powers" Or _
    ARange(1).Value = "Hermkens" Or ARange(1).Value = "Licka" Or _
    ARange(1).Value = "Fout" Or ARange(1).Value = "Marrin" Or _
    ARange(1).Value = "Fleming" Or ARange(1).Value = "Waiblinger" Or _
    ARange(1).Value = "Lambertson" Or ARange(1).Value = "Solis" Or _
    ARange(1).Value = "Deot" Or ARange(1).Value = "Large" Or _
    ARange(1).Value = "Gannon" Or ARange(1).Value = "FAUGHNAN" Or _
    ARange(1).Value = "COMPLIANCE" Or ARange(1).Value = "Jacobs" Or _
    ARange(1).Value = "Powers" Or ARange(1).Value = "TSH" Or _
    ARange(1).Value = "WRONG LOCATION CODE" _
Then
    If DRange Is Nothing Then
        Set DRange = ARange
    Else
        Set DRange = Union(DRange, ARange)
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Is _ underscore because if I just use return/enter to move to a new line I get an error in the complier

Comment: Exactly, underscore specifies that you're continuing the statement on a new line.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
If ARange(1).Value = "John" Or _
   ARange(1).Value = "Thomson" Or _
   ARange(1).Value = "Mattson" Or _
   ARange(1).Value = "Powers" Or _
   ARange(1).Value = "Hermkens" Or _
   ARange(1).Value = "Licka" Or _
   ARange(1).Value = "Fout" Or _
   ARange(1).Value = "Marrin" Or _
   ARange(1).Value = "Fleming" Or _
   ARange(1).Value = "Waiblinger" Or _
   ARange(1).Value = "Lambertson" Or _
   ARange(1).Value = "Solis" Or _
   ARange(1).Value = "Deot" Or _
   ARange(1).Value = "Large" Or _
   ARange(1).Value = "Gannon" Or _
   ARange(1).Value = "FAUGHNAN" Or _
   ARange(1).Value = "COMPLIANCE" Or _
   ARange(1).Value = "Jacobs" Or _
   ARange(1).Value = "Powers" Or _
   ARange(1).Value = "TSH" Or _
   ARange(1).Value = "WRONG LOCATION CODE" Then
```